# Casting an object into boolean throwing Exception

Tags: java, boolean

I am getting the data from hibernate native query and that is of Object type to 
which  i need to convert into boolean, I am doing this way..

```
Boolean b = ((java.lang.Boolean) ((Object[]) object)[++i]);
```

Now i need to set it into pojo there is a method as ..

```
public void setActive(boolean active)
 { this.active = active; }
```

when I am trying to set into pojo it is throwing an exceptiion

```
 b1.setActive(b);
```

please advise

Comment: What is the exception? Also, `b1` is a `Boolean`, which does not have a `setActive` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just simply have your variables wrong. You should call `b.setActive(b1);`. The Boolean object does not have a setActive method, you are calling it probably on the wrong object.

If you had a cast issue, an exception would be thrown when you cast the object to type Boolean before you call any methods on it.

Comment: sorry there was a typo mistake now pls look into updated post

Comment: Well, after that typo fix, I think it's best to let us know what's the exception you are getting. :) Not sure what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `b1.setActive(b!=null?b.booleanValue():false)`

[Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) class has booleanValue() methos which returns boolean value.

make sure `object` is `boolean[]`

Comment: Is `b.booleanValue()` really necessary with autoboxing? And you should try to avoid negation (`if (x!=y) { } else { }`) so a more readable way could be `b1.setActive(b==null?false:b);`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the getter (b.booleanValue()).
2. Autoboxing and unboxing is null sensitive

> ```
> Boolean b = null;
> boolean p =  b; //throws NPE
> ```